# RDS MySQL failing import from S3 - unable to extract the backup files of type xbstream

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to migrate a MySQL database from outside of AWS into an account.
I have been following the steps outlined in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.html

I am getting the error:

> Database instance put into incompatible-restore. Unable to extract the
>   backup files of type XBSTREAM. Please verify that your backup files in
>   bucket_name/prefix_name/ are in a valid format

The export is being created from a docker container running MySQL 5.7.22. The backup files are named `backup.xbstream<number>` (ie .xbstream00, .xbstream01, etc), are in an S3 bucket owned by the account and in the same region as the RDS instance, and are stored in the prefix I provide to the configuration.

To create the export collection that I upload to S3, I am running:

```
docker run --rm -it -v <volume_id>:/var/lib/mysql -v <volume_id_2>:/xtrabackup_backupfiles \
    perconalab/percona-xtrabackup --backup --host=<host_ip> --user=<user> --password=<password> \
    --stream=xbstream  --target-dir=/xtrabackup_backupfiles/xtrabackup_backupfiles \
    | split -d --bytes=500MB - <destination>/backup.xbstream
```

Really not sure how to trouble shoot further. Hoping somebody has some idea of what to check.

Comment: I am also having issues with the XBSTREAM S3 restore. Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: @getglad also faced this issue. Could you pls share a wrokaround?

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you find a solution?